# React Native fb-sdk cannot find symbol CallbackManager

Tags: react-native, react-native-fbsdk

React Native and fbsdk versions:

```
"react": "16.6.3",
"react-native": "0.58.5",
"react-native-fbsdk": "^0.8.0"
```

I got the following error:

```
> Task :app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac FAILED
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\project\MainApplication.java:22: error: cannot find symbol
  private static CallBackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
                 ^
  symbol:   class CallBackManager
  location: class MainApplication
C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\project\android\app\src\main\java\com\project\MainApplication.java:24: error: cannot find symbol
  protected static CallBackManager getCallbackManager() {
                   ^
  symbol:   class CallBackManager
  location: class MainApplication
2 errors

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

The issue seems to be related to this part of the code, but I can't quite figure out what's wrong. I followed exactly the instructions provided in their [official repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk).

```
public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private static CallBackManager mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

  protected static CallBackManager getCallbackManager() {
    return mCallbackManager;
  }

  // ...

  @Override
  protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager)
    );
  }

  // ...

}
```

I also manually added the following imports to `MainActivity.java`:

```
import com.facebook.CallbackManager;
import com.facebook.FacebookSdk;
import com.facebook.reactnative.androidsdk.FBSDKPackage;
```

Added these lines to `app/build.gradle`:

```
implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
```

and these to `settings.gradle`:

```
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
```

Comment: Can you show you `app/build.gradle` and your `settings.gradle`?

Comment: I added these lines to `app/build.gradle`:

implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'

and these to `settings.gradle`:

include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')

Comment: You don't need `implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'` as react-native-fbsdk already uses 4.38 version of fb android sdk.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, removing this line does not resolve the problem though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If someone happens to stumble across the very same issue, this is related to npm not linking fb-sdk to the project properly. I tried using `npm install` and `npm link`, but had no success, despite npm not throwing any errors. However, installing the sdk using `react-native` resolved the issue:

```
react-native install react-native-fbsdk
react-native link react-native-fbsdk
```

Should you run into a [MODULE_NOT_FOUND](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/13176) error while attempting to link, open the command line on the project root folder and run:

```
cd android
gradlew clean
```

Additionally, while their official [GitHub repository](https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk) does contain instructions regarding the installation process, I recommend following the [facebook developers page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/react-native/configure-android-current) instead, as it is a lot better in terms of readability and details.